# Android OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an app that downloads byte data and shoves them into bitmaps.  The bitmaps original size is 640x480, then we shrink them down in the app.  I don't have any specific code to show, but I am wondering what are the best practices when managing bitmaps.  I know the errors are related to the bitmaps.  Here is one of the errors I see:

09-12 10:38:42.312 E/dalvikvm-heap(22518): 1228800-byte external allocation too large for this process.

Also, inDither = true and inPrefferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Any thoughts?

Comment: This post will help you in how to manage bitmaps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue